# How to parse escaped Json using JSONObject in android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I'm unable to parse escaped json string through JSONObject, while trying to parse it, I always get an Unterminated Object error. But when I manually remove all of the escape characters from the json string, JSONObject parses it successfully.

But the problem is that for complex or nested json strings, I don't want to remove escape characters, because for nested structures, unescaping the characters results in an invalid json string.

This is the json string after removing escapes characters and I get unterminated object error due to invalid json when parsing through JSONObject

```
{"result":"unknown","message":"{"firebase":"unknown"}","sender":"unknown"}
```

This is the unescaped json string

```
{"result":"unknown","message":"{\"firebase\":\"unknown\"}","sender":"unknown"}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you fix the source of the JSON if at all possible rather than try to fix it later

Comment: Alternatively, `"{\"firebase\":\"unknown\"}"` is a single String. Why have you sent a JSON object as a message string?

Comment: For some reasons, i cannot update the incoming json.

Comment: So, you've tried `new JSONObject(response.getString("message"))`?

Comment: I cannot do response.getString() on a plain String Object! i-e incoming response is String

Comment: Okay, then convert that string into JSON first. The escaped values are correct. No need to remove them

Comment: thanks @cricket_007 i've fixed the issue, i was not unescaping the json properly. Now able to parse json using JSONObject. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the json you are constructing it in wrong format.

In case of escaped json

```
{
    "result":"unknown",
    "message":"{"firebase":"unknown"}",
    "sender":"unknown"
}
```

the json object "message" is having value "{" and firebase is causing exception.

In the the escaped json `"message":{"firebase":"unknown"}` will form valid json.

Comment: thanks for help, issue fixed, i was unescaping incorrectly.

Comment: Unfortunately, not enough repo :(